# Docker-compose string interpolation causes type conversion issue in spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I am running a stack of services/applications and would like to deploy these using a single docker-compose file. I tested this and it works flawlessly. But now, when I try to make the docker-compose file more configurable by having an .env file take control of the configuration the spring boot project that has to be deployed gives me the following error:

```
api                | Failed to bind properties under 'spring.data.mongodb.port' to java.lang.Integer:
api                | 
api                |     Property: spring.data.mongodb.port
api                |     Value: '27017'
api                |     Origin: System Environment Property "spring.data.mongodb.port"
api                |     Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer (caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'27017'")
```

The env file I am using:

```
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
```

How the back-end is receiving the configuration request in spring boot's application.properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

The problem is clear, but how do I make sure that whenever the environment variable arrives, the '27017' in String format is casted to an Integer?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message complains on the value `"'27017'"`. Try specifying it without single quotes.

Comment: Could you join your `docker-compose.yaml` file to your question? And your build directory structure if necessary.

Comment: @dekkard thanks for your reply. But like you can see in my env file, it is without single quotes. Passing an integer as an environment variables automatically converts it to a string, which causes issues in this case.

Comment: Indeed, what @dekkard said was right. In my docker-compose.yml file I did a String interpolation like the following: '${PORT}'. Indeed the single quotes were the mistakes. Now the  back-end actually accepts the environment variable binding. Thank you as well Martin for making me look at my compose file again